# how to call system() with 2 arguments in vim

Tags: system, vim

```
function! ReName()
   let old_name = expand("<cword>")
    let new_name = input("new name: ",old_name)
    let cmd = "ref.sh ".expand(old_name).expand(" ").expand(new_name)
   :call system(cmd)
endfunction
```

ref.sh is a bash file, context is

```
#! /bin/bash
find . -name '*.[ch]' | xargs sed -i s/$1/$2/g
```

but now, when i use ReName function in vim, it does not work.

Answer (score 3):

*Well, what do you expect it to do, and what / where is the error?*

First of all, you ignore the output from the call to `system()`. If there is output, either use `:echo` instead of `:call`, assign it to a variable, or `:return` it. Otherwise, check the `v:shell_error` variable for the exit status of the command.

---

Some more critiques: Instead of

```
let cmd = "ref.sh ".expand(old_name).expand(" ").expand(new_name)
```

leave out the superfluous `expand()`:

```
let cmd = "ref.sh ".old_name." ".new_name
```

or assemble the command via `printf()`:

```
let cmd = printf("ref.sh %s %s", old_name, new_name)
```

---

Your function will only work for certain, well-behaved arguments. Use `shellescape()` in Vim, and proper quoting in your shell script.

Comment: try this ways,but Still can not execute the script!

Answer (score 1):

I agree with *Ingo Karkat*. Other way could be to substitute

```
:call system(cmd)
```

<s>that it's incorrect with the colon inside the `vimrc`,</s> with

```
exe "!" . cmd
```

assuming that your `cmd` has not special characters like spaces, newlines os something like that.

Comment: You can use `:call`; but the `:` is only necessary when typing (to enter command-line mode), optional in a script.

Comment: @IngoKarkat: Thank you. Edited to fix it.

Comment: it's over.The reason is that the path for the bash.thank you!